# How do flight crews handle a death aboard a commercial aircraft?

Tags: airlines, crew, flight-attendant

Kinda a morbid subject I know, but whether a prince or a street sweeper, we all dance with the Grim Reaper - sooner or later.  And there’s no reason he cannot visit you at 30,000 feet, if it’s your time.  Therefore if a person, or a member of the flight crew succumbs and dies, how is this handled in a professional manner?

Comment: That's what ejection seats are for.

Comment: Burial at sea for transoceanic flights?